# How to prevent line wrapping in code, but allow it in help/info buffers?

Tags: major-mode, wrapping

I'm quite new to emacs (coming from vim), and I'm struggling to figure out how to configure sane line-wrapping/truncation behavior.

For the most part, I'd like to prevent wrapping, so I put this in my init file:

```
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
```

But for help/info buffers, I do want wrapping.

Basically, I want truncation in buffers that contain code, and wrapping in buffers that contain text. What's a sensible way to achieve this? I imagine I want to keep the above default, but override it for certain major modes (e.g. Help), but I'm not sure how to do that.

*update based on [Kaushal Modi's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24780/8528)*

```
(defun my-truncate-lines-disable () (setq truncate-lines nil))
(add-hook 'help-mode-hook #'my-truncate-lines-disable)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```el
(defun my-truncate-lines-disable ()
  "Disable line truncation, even in split windows."
  (let ((inhibit-message t) ; No messages in the echo area - needs emacs 25+
        message-log-max ; No messages in the *Messages* buffer
        truncate-partial-width-windows) ; No truncation in split windows
    (toggle-truncate-lines 0)))
(add-hook 'help-mode-hook #'my-truncate-lines-disable)
```

Comment: Though your solution works, it leads to another problem: how to prevent toggle-truncate-lines from displaying "Truncate long lines disabled" in the echo area. Is there another way I could do this using "primitives"?

Comment: I took a look at the definition of toggle-truncate-lines and it turned out to be pretty simple.

Comment: @ivan I have updated my answer which works on emacs 25+ (you can try out its [latest pretest version](http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/)). The same code will be fine on older emacsen too, just that setting `inhibit-message` to `t` will not do anything.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I'm using the emacs mac port, so I'm stuck on 24.5.1 for now. Anyway, this forced me to take a look at the implementation of toggle-truncate-lines and pick out just the part I needed. That also gave me an appreciation for how accessible the various layers of emacs' source code are, which is a big change from vim.