# How can I display continuation lines only for csv-mode?

Tags: csv, truncate-lines

By default I have set truncate-lines to `t`,  (*do not display continuation lines*), hence I want to enable it for csv-mode by default.

Code section related to `truncate-lines` in my config file.

```lisp
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook
          (lambda () (setq truncate-lines nil)))
(setq-default truncate-lines t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-t") 'toggle-truncate-lines)
```

---

I have tried to add following lines, which did not work:

```lisp
(defun my-truncate-lines-disables ()
  (setq truncate-lines nil))
(add-hook 'csv-mode-hook 'my-truncate-lines-disables)
```

Related: [How to prevent line wrapping in code, but allow it in help/info buffers?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24779/how-to-prevent-line-wrapping-in-code-but-allow-it-in-help-info-buffers)

Comment: What version of emacs are you using? What does `C-h f csv-mode` say? What does `C-h v csv-mode-hook` say? BTW, although this has nothing to do with the problem you see, the function is named misleadingly: it `disables` truncation of lines.

Comment: `csv-mode  c  ()  Major mode for editing files of comma-separated value type.` | `csv-mode-hook  v  nil  Hook run after entering CSV mode.`. I have updated the function name.

Comment: It should work then. It works fine here.

Comment: What happens when you run `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` two times? do you have a better view for a long line csv file? I can see its real affect first disabling Truncate long  and than re-enable Truncate long lines

Comment: It goes to truncated lines and then back again, just as expected. I don't understand what you are asking: what's a "better" view? They are two different views.

Comment: At first  truncated lines does not look as it should be for a very long line. But after I do truncated lines and then back again it corrects the look it has, having continues lines. Better view has csv-mode align columns.